# Aggregate @property child fields?

Tags: django

In Django I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    @property
    def total_invoice_amount(self):
        return self.invoiceline_set.aggregate(Sum('price_incl_vat'))['price_incl_vat']


class InvoiceLine(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    price_per_unit = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=10)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(staticdata.models.Unit)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=10)
    vat_percentage = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=4, max_digits=10)

    # Calculated fields
    @property
    def price_excl_vat(self):
        return self.price_per_unit * self.amount

    @property
    def vat_amount(self):
        return self.price_excl_vat * self.vat_percentage / 100

    @property
    def price_incl_vat(self):
        return self.price_excl_vat + self.vat_amount
```

I'd like to have a total invoice amount which is an aggregated sum of the computed field price_incl_vat. So I constructed total_invoice_amount like this:

```
@property
def total_invoice_amount(self):
    return self.invoiceline_set.aggregate(Sum('price_incl_vat'))['price_incl_vat']
```

But apparently that doesn't work:

> Cannot resolve keywork 'price_incl_vat' into field.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is not directly possible with the aggregate function, so I solved it this way:

```
@property
def total_invoice_amount(self):
    total = 0

    for invoice_line in self.invoiceline_set.all():
        total += invoice_line.price_incl_vat

    return total
```